Setting the elevation of my card is not showing
I am using implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"). Why is the elevation of my card not showing?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/vibrant_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/neutral_light_gray"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bangkoCentralImage"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:foregroundGravity="left"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bangko_sentral"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bangkoCentralImage"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                    android:text="Inventory Management System"
                    android:textColor="@color/neutral_charcoal_gray"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLoadFile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load File" />

</RelativeLayout>


Please ignore my previous comment. I didn't notice that you'd redefined card_view on the <CardView> tag. My bad. That said, your setup works just fine for me, both in the layout editor and at runtime.
